# How can I search the string X times in the DB? (MYSQL + PHP)

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hey, first I use SQL + PHP the type of DB is MYSQL.

I have a column with the many strings, but I want to search the string 08/08/10 if it exists 5 times for example in the column, how do I do it?

** If I will do:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE y LIKE '%08/08/10%'
```

Maybe it exists, but I don't know if 5 times..

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch rows where the string exists at least once and use php (e.g. substr_count) to count occurrences.

```
foreach($db->fetchAll(" where y like '%blah%' ") as $rec)
   if(substr_count($rec->y, "blah") == 5)
       bingo...
```

it also may help to tell us more about your problem - maybe there are better ways to structure the database

Comment: I tried the solution of Alexander but its what I search of..
But your answer its what I search of.. So, thank you very much!
I just change the loop from foreach to while ans its working perffect.
Thank you again. Luis.

Answer (score 3):

`select count(1) from x where y like '%08/08/10%'` -outputs exact number of rows that have y like '%08/08/10%'

no group by needed in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didnt know about this function in SQL. Again - thank you!!